# Speed Control of MediaPlayer in Android

Tags: android

I am developing a player app and I am using [`MediaPlayer`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) for that.

Now, I want to change the speed of the playing track.

I've seen so many apps with this functionality. How can I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Control the playback speed of Android MediaPlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406169/control-the-playback-speed-of-android-mediaplayer)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The **MediaPlayer does not** provide this feature but SoundPool has this functionality.
The SoundPool class has a method called `setRate (int streamID, float rate)`. If you are interested in the [API have a look here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html#setRate%28int,%20float%29).

This Snippet will work.

```
 float playbackSpeed=1.5f; 
 SoundPool soundPool = new SoundPool(4, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 100);

 soundId = soundPool.load(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                         + "/sample.3gp", 1);
 AudioManager mgr = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
 final float volume = mgr.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

 soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener()
 {
     @Override
     public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool arg0, int arg1, int arg2)
     {
         soundPool.play(soundId, volume, volume, 1, 0, playbackSpeed);
     }
 });
```

Comment: No MediaPlayer does not provide this functionality.

Comment: If I get it correctly it means pitch will be also changed? Is there method to adjust speed without changing pitch?

Comment: SoundPool is only good for about 5.5 seconds of playback.   For Lollipop and earlier, I just don't provide the option for speed control. And, yeah, I just got a band new tablet that happened to be Lollipop.

Answer (score 57):

**Beginning API 23**, MediaPlayer can set playback speed using [this method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setPlaybackParams%28android.media.PlaybackParams%29).

> Class MediaPlayer
>
> `public void setPlaybackParams (PlaybackParams params)` Added in API
>   level 23
>
> Sets playback rate using PlaybackParams. Parameters params
>     PlaybackParams: the playback params. Throws IllegalStateException   if
>   the internal player engine has not been initialized.
>   IllegalArgumentException  if params is not supported.

Sample code:

```
MediaPlayer mp = ...; //Whatever
float speed = 0.75f;     
mp.setPlaybackParams(mp.getPlaybackParams().setSpeed(speed));
```

**For API < 23**, refer to [Vipul Shah's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10850224) above (or below).

Comment: For those of you who are getting an IllegalStateException while calling the 'setPlayParams' method, make sure you're not doing PlaybackParams params = mp.getPlaybackParams(), set the speed and then pass it to mp.setPlaybackParams()! Set the speed DIRECTLY while calling the mp.getPlayParams()! Just like in Shishir Gupta's answer!

Answer (score 17):

soundpool only supports relatively small sound effect files that can be preloaded. You will get heap overflows with any useful length music track.

Comment: is this sure? anyone can confirm this answer? thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Now you can use

`mediaPlayer.setPlaybackParams(mediaPlayer.getPlaybackParams().setSpeed(speed))`

for API 23 and up!

Comment: Please note if you want to promote your own product/blog you **must disclose your affiliation in the answer**, otherwise your answer may be flagged as spam. Please read [How to not be a spammer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion)

Comment: Also, this answer does already seem to be covered in @ShishirGupta's answer above

Answer (score 2):

The `MediaPlayer` class doesn't give this functionality. Instead use the `SoundPool` class. It has a method called `setRate (int streamID, float rate)`. Read [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html#setRate%28int,%20float%29) for further info. Here is a [sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751309/change-the-playback-rate-of-a-track-in-real-time-on-android) for you to work with it.

Comment: Yeah. Then Can I set other functionalities like next track, previous track, sound control, forward, backward, sleep, repeat, shuffle in SoundPool? Please give me some idea.

Comment: You can search for tutorials on the [Google](http://www.google.com). you will find many examples for this.

Answer (score 2):

According to the flow that had mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45613064/13634739)  following codes are for android API 23 (Android 6.0 Marshmallow)

```
PlaybackParams playbackParams = new PlaybackParams();
playbackParams.setSpeed(2);
playbackParams.setPitch(1);
playbackParams.setAudioFallbackMode(
    PlaybackParams.AUDIO_FALLBACK_MODE_DEFAULT);
mMediaPlayer.setPlaybackParams(playbackParams);
```

Comment: Add some explanation to your answer . Code only answer are not really useful .

Answer (score 2):

**Speed Control by ExoPlayer in Android**

```
//exoPlayer.setPlaybackParameters(PlaybackParameters(//speed in float))
//EXAMPLE->
exoPlayer.setPlaybackParameters(PlaybackParameters(1.5f))
```