# speed control for android mediaplayer

Tags: java, android

I have a project that I used android MediaPlayer in it.

now in a part of my project I need to change the speed of playing of MediaPlayer.

But I find out that mediaplayer does not support speed control and I should use soundpool for this.and soundpool does not support seek that I need seek in my project.please help me.how can I add speedcontrol for this part.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [stackoverflow/2618110](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37094353/2618110). You can use MediaPlayer method:
    *public void setPlaybackParams (PlaybackParams params);*
to do that.