# How to adjust play speed of video on android?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-mediacodec

I need to implement a requriment of adjust play speed when playing a video, how can I do that using Android API (MediaPlayer) or other 3rd-party library? I google it, and no any idea by far. Any suggestions welcome, thank you.

Comment: It isn't included in the public version yet, but ExoPlayer is working on adding support for adjusting playback speed. One can track the progress of this feature in GitHub: https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/26

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Media player does not provide what you want.
You have to use some other android api.

check link. [Speed Control of MediaPlayer in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849961/speed-control-of-mediaplayer-in-android)

Or you can use media player with PlaybackParams(added in 23 api)

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/PlaybackParams.html

Answer (score 1):

You can also use different media playback library than android built in, for example [ExoMedia](https://github.com/brianwernick/ExoMedia) that also works below android 23 ,has same api as video view and allow you to set the PlaybackParams including speed.