# YouTube video speed controller by YouTube API in Android

Tags: android, api, youtube, youtube-api

How to work with speed of video in YouTube API android application development?

Comment: Possible answer to your question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42777444/how-to-adjust-play-speed-of-video-on-android.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use fragment in these cases. 
Else using a simple layout can increase your speed of video for some limit but in most of the cases it is just useless.