# How to increase speed of online audio play using MediaPlayer

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

How can I increase a speed of online audio playing using `MediaPlayer`. Is it possible? How?

I found this code:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    mMediaPlayer.setPlaybackParams(new PlaybackParams().setSpeed(2.0f));
}
```

but works only on above marshmallow version

Comment: you can check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849961/speed-control-of-mediaplayer-in-android/37094353) about speed control.

Comment: yes you are right but this is done after downloading audio file and get audio path, i want to play audio online url,