# how to control the speed of a recording file in android MediaPlayer, or AudioTrack

Tags: java, android, performance, audio, audio-recording

how can I control the speed of an audio recording
other than soundpool on android

```
MediaPlayer

or

AudioTrack
```

Is there another?

Comment: Is it programming question?

Comment: see the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849961/speed-control-of-mediaplayer-in-android

Comment: Is there anything other than soundpool?, yes, 
if it's a programming question