# Increase Media Playback Speed in Android[Sound pool doesn't work]

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, soundpool, mediaplayback

I am creating a Media Player app. Everything is working fine but I want to give option to increase playback speed, for eg. `1.5x`,`2x` etc. I saw few **Stack Overflow** questions and they all suggested to use **Sound Pool** for this as Media Player doesn't support this thing. But from following link
[Speed Control in Media Player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849961/speed-control-of-mediaplayer-in-android) and this [Changing PlayBack Rate of Track](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751309/change-the-playback-rate-of-a-track-in-real-time-on-android)

it is suggested that Sound Pool is only suitable for **small file sizes for upto 1 MB** and is also limited to **increasing speed only to 2x** and all those answers are about 6 years old. So are there any other alternatives available now.

**EDIT:** As **Ian Lake** suggested Using `getPlayBackParams()` is an option to do so but is only available from API 23 but my app has to support at least API level 14.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, `MediaPlayer` **does** support playback rate changes via [setPlaybackParams()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setPlaybackParams(android.media.PlaybackParams)) and [PlaybackParams#setSpeed()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/PlaybackParams.html#setSpeed(float)). However, those APIs were only added in Marshmallow, API 23. This was [long standing feature request for ExoPlayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/26) that has recently [been implemented](https://medium.com/google-exoplayer/variable-speed-playback-with-exoplayer-e6e6a71e0343) and is available back to API 16.

Comment: Are there any other option available??